# Can use first image set as product image from product galleries in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I tried this way, but it's still cannot generate a product image at the metabox.

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_placeholder_img_src',                                 
    'growdev_custom_woocommerce_placeholder', 10 );
    function growdev_custom_woocommerce_placeholder( $image_url ) {
    $product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID());
    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();
    if ( is_array( $attachment_ids ) && !empty($attachment_ids) ) {
    $first_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_ids[0] );
    $image_url = $first_image_url;  // change this to the URL to your custom placeholder
    return $image_url;
} // No images found
else {
    $image_url = 'https://...jpg';
    return $image_url;
    // @TODO
}
     }
```

I searched on Google and there is no way to use the first image set as product image from product galleries automatically.